# How can I receive a file sent with FormData on the server (Express.js)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, xmlhttprequest

I have image files appended to a new Form data. I then need to grab the file on the backend so I can upload it to S3 (it has to be uploaded on the server side). The thing is I cannot access the file on the backend. I tried multiple middlewares, such as Formidable, express-fileupload, etc., but they all need me to have an input field name in order to access the uploaded file. Since this is not an HTML form, I don't have an input field (or don't know where to look for one), so I cannot parse the request and get the uploaded file.

Here's my code (options are the files chosen by the user to be uploaded). I tried POST as well, to no avail, am now using GET to pass along some parameters I will need later on:

```
    function onUploadFiles(survey, options) {

    var formData = new FormData();


    var file = options.files[0];
    formData.append(file.name, file);
    
}

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(
      "GET",
      `/logmood?file-name=${file.name}&file-type=${file.type}`,
    ); // https://surveyjs.io/api/MySurveys/uploadFiles
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    };
    xhr.send(formData);
```

So, on the server side I need to get the file appended, and then proceed with doing this and that, in my case uploading to S3, and this I cannot achieve. The libraries offers solutions like this one, bu, once again, I have no input field:

You're uploading a file called car.jpg.
Your input's name field is foo: `<input name="foo" type="file" />`.
In your express server request, you can access your uploaded file from req.files.foo:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files.foo); // the uploaded file object
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multer library to upload the files in express js
https://github.com/expressjs/multer